# Best approach to send Windows Store App data from server periodically?

Tags: sockets, windows-8, client-server, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am aware of the [`StreamSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.aspx) class and have looked heavily into this, to the point of having a [working client-server example](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/streamsocket-example-c-metro) running in my Windows Store app, however, when I try to then move out my server code to a separate WPF app, console app or Windows Service, so I can attempt to connect with my client and have data received into it, it cannot find the `Windows.Networking.Sockets` namespace, which I imagine is due to the fact that is exclusive to Win RT / Windows Store apps.

So..

1. What is the point of `StreamSocket` if you can only use it on Windows Store apps, surely you aren't going to run a server which serves to a group of clients as a Windows Store app..
2. What approach should I choose to implement what I need to do, which is sending data to a Windows Store app from the server periodically and potentially the client sending stuff back?

One thing that has cropped up in my mind, is I would like to support a chat feature, and obviously would not want to be polling the server for a JSON request every 5 seconds, I know there must be an elegant solution as I've seen some Windows Store apps implementing things like this, for instance the word game WordFeud makes heavy use of client-server activitiy, so what is the best practice to handling all this stuff?

Really confused, help!

Comment: Maybe you can use the push mechanism Windows 8 introduces http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465460.aspx. For the chat thing: Why not use the built in Messanger-App?

Comment: Interesting prospect, but sorry I need it all integrated for a game I'm working on.

Comment: [this article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457335/How-to-call-WinRT-APIs-from-NET-desktop-apps) seems promising

Comment: I'm actually in the midst of investigating using [`Microsoft.WebSockets`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WebSockets) via an ASP.NET Web Api project + [`MessageWebSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh994397.aspx) for the Win RT side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you you looked into the Azure Mobile Services? you can get trial account to experiment. but the AMS may be the way to go. it proves among other things push notification, scheduling, etc. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/

and it can be used from Windwos Store, Windows Phone 8, iOS, Android, and HTML... check it out...

hope this helps!

joelcitizen